# Is there a Twilio outbound SMS magic number that hits a timeout value?

Tags: twilio, sms, outbound

I'm testing some flows that use outbound SMS via Twilio and have been really pleased and impressed by the magic numbers provided e.g. https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials

However, I'm interested to see how our application responds if there's some issue sending an SMS to a number where it essentially hits a timeout value.  I haven't found a magic number such as this or know of a way to recreate the scenario, can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were using a real auth credentials and real phone number (instead of magic number), I suspect Twilio just queues the request on their side and responds with a HTTP 201, so you'll always get a very fast response from Twilio, but it doesn't necessarily mean the message has been sent to a carrier and delivered to a device.

If you're using Twilio messaging services, you can subscribe to delivery status callbacks to get the status of a SMS e.g. sending, sent, delivered, failed, etc - see [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/confirm-delivery-csharp-aspnet-mvc#receive-status-events-in-your-web-application). Note: I don't know if you'd receive callbacks with magic numbers - I suspect not... either way you can provision a Twilio phone number pretty cheaply to test e.g. in Australia (where I'm from) I can purchase a AU phone number for $6 per month and I can release the phone number when ever I want to stop getting billed for it...

If you just want your app to timeout on invocation of the Twilio API you can do something like the following (in .NET core) to force timeout a request in a specified amount of time (1 second in example below):

```cs
using var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
   response = await twilioHttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"2010-04-01/Accounts/{accountSID}/Messages.json", request, jsonSerializerOptions, tokenSource.Token);
```

If timeout is exceeded, an exception will be thrown that you can handle. Note: there's various networking tools that can be used to block or limit outbound requests, which you can use to test timeout scenarios.